# Where the "BYTE_ORDER" macro is defined in OSX?

Tags: c, macos, unix, endianness

I want use "BYTE_ORDER" macro in my Xcode project but i can't because i don't know in which header it's defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I look in my Xcode 4.3.X installation, I find the "`byte_order.h`" file located in a few places:

```
[/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform]:;!fi
find . -name byte_order.h -print
./Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Kernel.framework/Versions/A/Headers/architecture/byte_order.h
./Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Kernel.framework/Versions/A/Headers/machine/byte_order.h
./Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include/architecture/byte_order.h
./Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include/architecture/i386/byte_order.h
./Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include/architecture/ppc/byte_order.h
./Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include/machine/byte_order.h
./Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Kernel.framework/Versions/A/Headers/architecture/byte_order.h
./Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Kernel.framework/Versions/A/Headers/machine/byte_order.h
./Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/usr/include/architecture/byte_order.h
./Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/usr/include/architecture/i386/byte_order.h
./Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/usr/include/machine/byte_order.h
```

You'd probably want to do a "`#include <architecture/byte_order.h>`" in your .c file in order to pick up the byte_order macros.

For the actual "`BYTE_ORDER`" define itself, well that's defined in a few specific places but the way it's defined seems meant for very specific purposes.  For example, this define:

```
#define __DARWIN_BYTE_ORDER __DARWIN_LITTLE_ENDIAN
#define BYTE_ORDER  __DARWIN_BYTE_ORDER
./Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Kernel.framework/Versions/A/Headers/i386/endian.h
```

is meant only for Kernel Extensions (drivers).

And this define:

```
#     define BYTE_ORDER LITTLE_ENDIAN
#     define BYTE_ORDER BIG_ENDIAN
#  endif /* BYTE_ORDER */
#  define X_BYTE_ORDER BYTE_ORDER
./Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/usr/X11/include/X11/Xarch.h
```

is meant for X11 stuff (ewww).

I'd say the best thing to do is use the "`NXHostByteOrder`" inline function in the "`byte_order.h`" file, and this will give you the byte order of the current host.

Comment: It seems that `byte_order.h` doesn't contain the macro `BYTE_ORDER`: http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/architecture/architecture-260/byte_order.h

Comment: yep... just noticed that.  I'll modify my answer a little bit.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately "NXHostByteOrder" can't be used in a preprocessor condition (as far as i know) unlike "BYTE_ORDER" macro. Just out of curiosity... Do you think that "NSHostByteOrder" is built upon "NXHostByteOrder"?